# Troubleshooting General Slowness?

Tags: globals

We have a Global page that has about 10 tabs with a bunch of fields each. The thing takes between 50 and 80 seconds to load. The debugger shows that it fires off over 9000 events and makes almost 900 db queries. I'm trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this in order to try to speed it up. It appears that each time afterRenderTemplate is fired, it takes 5 or more seconds before getting to the next step.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Could be a plugin. Start by disabling all your plugin with `'disabledPlugins' => '*',` in your `config/general.php` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#disabledplugins)). If things speed up, try to re-add them one by one to find the guilty one.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I disabled every plugin and the global didn't even speed up by one second. I'm guessing I just have too many fields (many of them Matrix Fields) in there.